# Why Linux Kernel ZONE_NORMAL is limited to 896 MB?

Tags: linux, kernel

A newbie question. I'm doing some kernel study and get confused on the
896MB size limit of ZONE_NORMAL. I don't understand why kernel cannot
map 4G physical memory into kernel space directly. Some documents
mentioned its size constraint of page map. But considering 4G memory
has 2^20 pages and each "struct page" is 4 bytes, the mem_map would
only be 4MB. That should not be the issue. Hope you could shed me some
light.

Thanks

Comment: Apart from what others have mentioned in the answers, I have read that the 896 MiB limit is adjustable at the time of kernel configuration (in Linux Device drivers 3rd edition)

Answer (score 10):

Of course, the kernel can map all available memory.

In Linux, the memory available from all banks is classified into "nodes". These nodes are used to indicate how much memory each bank has. Memory in each node is divided into "zones". The zones currently defined are `ZONE_DMA`, `ZONE_NORMAL` and `ZONE_HIGHMEM`.

`ZONE_DMA` is used by some devices for data transfer and is mapped in the lower physical memory range (up to 16 MB).

Memory in the `ZONE_NORMAL` region is mapped by the kernel in the upper region of the linear address space. Most operations can only take place in `ZONE_NORMAL`; so this is the most performance critical zone. `ZONE_NORMAL` goes from 16 MB to 896 MB.

*Why?*

Part of memory is reserved for kernel data structures that store information about the memory map and page tables. This on x86 is 128 MB. Hence, of the 1 GB physical memory the kernel can access (on a typical configuration, 1GB is reserved for the kernel), 128MB is reserved. Hence the kernel virtual addresses in this 128 MB are not mapped to physical memory directly. This leaves a maximum of 896 MB for `ZONE_NORMAL`. So, even if one has 1 GB of physical RAM, just 896 MB will be actually available for userspace.

To better understand the subject, I suggest you have a look at Chapter 15 of Linux Device Drivers ([pdf](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch15.pdf)).

Comment: Thanks Michael. I understand that only 896MB physical RAM can be directly mapped by kernel virtual address. By my questions why user cannot see 896MB-4GMB physical memory. Anyway, kernel space is capable to hold all 2^20 pages representing 4GB Physical Memory. It should be able to allocate some high-mem pages to user space process.  Thanks

Answer (score 9):

The reason why the kernel limits itself to 896 megabytes is for performance reasons.

The more space available to the kernel means *less* address space available to userspace. This 3/1 split means that the most amount of address space a user process can allocate is 3 gigabytes -- of course, due to memory fragmentation, in practice it seems to start failing around 2.5 gigabytes.

Different splits are available: 2/2 and 1/3 splits that allocate two gigabyte address space for the kernel and two gigabytes for userspace, and three gigabytes for the kernel and one gigabyte address space for userspace. (This `firefox` is *now* consuming 1249 megabytes, so it couldn't fit into one of those 1/3 split kernels.)

There are some kernels (perhaps vendor-only?) that support what is known as the 4:4 split -- four gigabytes of address space for the kernel and four gigabytes of address space for userspace. These are extremely useful for the 32-bit systems that have 32 or 64 gigabytes of memory -- since a large system probably has many disks, a lot of IO in flight, and needs significant buffering for both block devices and network traffic. However, these 4:4 kernels require flushing the TLB cache on entering and exiting every system call. These TLB flushes introduce significant slowdowns on "small" systems and are only worth it on "large" systems where the extra memory can cache enough disk / network resources to improve the performance of the system.

The other splits don't incur this TLB flush because the TLB maintains a permissions bit indicating whether the pages are available when the CPU is in user state or supervisor state: the kernel pages are always mapped, but marked available only when the CPU's supervisor flag is set. So entering and exiting the kernel is fast, when exiting back to the process that entered the kernel. When context-switching, of course the TLB needs to be flushed then.

Comment: Hi, Sarnold: Thank you for the answer. My question is: given 4GB PHYSICAL memory, why cannot we directly access the higher 3GB physical memory(ZONE_HIGHMEM)? Even considering Kernel virtual space is only 1GB, it's still large enough to hold all pages files. For reference, this [document](http://www.cs.miami.edu/~burt/learning/Csc521.071/notes/understand.pdf)  _italic_ **bold** `code` Page 48 said it's page map issues. I don't understand the way he calculates mem_map. Hope you could shed me some light.

Comment: The kernel doesn't even have to add to the mapped page tables on kernel entry - those kernel pages are always there, it's just that their PTEs have the User/Supervisor bit set to indicate that they're only accessible in Supervisor mode.

Comment: @caf: that would _also_ mean returning to the same process doesn't incur a flush, right?

Comment: I certainly can't explain it as well as Mel; check Page 131: _For mapping pages, a single page set of PTEs is stored at the beginning of the PKMap area to allow 1024 high pages to be mapped into low memory for short periods with the function `kmap()` and unmapped with `kunmap()`. The pool seems very small but the page is only mapped by `kmap()` for a_ very _short time._

Comment: @sarnold: I believe so (or another process with the same `mm`, ie. another thread).

Comment: @user1063294: The issue isn't the space for the page tables, it's the space for the pages themselves.  Each physical page you want to map takes up a virtual page - so if you only have 1G of virtual pages available, you can only map 1G of physical pages at a time.

Comment: @caf: For "virtual pages", do you mean the "struct PAGE"? Its size is 32bits. A real physical page frame is 4KB. So I don't think 1G virtual pages can only represent 1G physical pages.

Comment: @user1063294: No, I don't mean `struct page` - I mean a 4096 byte page frame in the virtual address space.  A 4096 byte physical page is made accessible by mapping it to a 4096 byte region of the virtual address space, and if there is only 1G of virtual address space available then only 1G of physical memory can be mapped there at any one time.